# How to return multiple types in APIFunction?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, api, apifunction, cloud-deploy

I'd like to publish an api that returns an image as well as a number, but it seems that the docs for APIFunction specifies only a single possible format type:

[image]

Here's an example to play with:

```
randomClock[t_] := Rasterize[Graphics[Rotate[ClockGauge[t][[1]], 
     RandomReal[{0, 2 \[Pi]}], {0, 0}], ImagePadding -> 0], ImageSize -> 300];

randomClockDeploy[] := With[{t = RandomChoice /@ Range /@ {12, 60, 60}}, 
     {randomClock[t], t}]

CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{}, randomClockDeploy[] &], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

This returns:

[image]

So what I'm looking for would be something akin to:

*CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{}, randomClockDeploy[] &, **{"PNG","String"}**], Permissions -> "Public"]*

Comment: You should probably return a JSON object in that case.

Comment: Encoding the image inside the Json, can u show code to do this with my example?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this (encoding the PNG in [Base64](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Base64.html)):

```
randomClock[t_] := 
  Rasterize[
   Graphics[
    Rotate[ClockGauge[t][[1]], RandomReal[{0, 2 \[Pi]}], {0, 0}], 
    ImagePadding -> 0], ImageSize -> 300];


randomClockDeploy[] := 
 With[{t = RandomChoice /@ Range /@ {12, 60, 60}}, <|
   "img" -> ExportString[randomClock[t], {"Base64", "PNG"}], 
   "text" -> ExportString[t, "Text"]|>]

CloudDeploy[
 APIFunction[{}, randomClockDeploy[] &, "JSON"], "clockJSON", 
 Permissions -> "Public"]
```

and a request to your API will receive this:

```
{
  "img": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh...EUgAA...kSuQmCC\n",
  "text": "7\n23\n38"
}
```

The "img" can be decoded by standard methods.  In WL you would do:

```
ImportString[
 URLExecute[apiEndPoint, {}, "RawJSON"]["img"], {"Base64", "PNG"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, you can have the JSON object return the URL of the image:

```
randomClockDeploy2[] :=
 With[{t = RandomChoice /@ Range /@ {12, 60, 60}}, <|
   "img" -> 
    URLShorten@
     URLBuild[{CloudDirectory[], 
       Export["test.png", randomClock[t], "PNG"]}], 
   "text" -> ExportString[t, "Text"]|>]
```

now the API returns:

```
{
  "img": "https://wolfr.am/faKeShoRT",
  "text": "12\n16\n12"
}
```